# Encrypt azure blob using Key in Azure-key-vault in Python

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, azure-keyvault, public-key-encryption, azure-container-service

Microsoft has an example in C# for encrypting azure blob using the key in azure-key-vault
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-encrypt-decrypt-blobs-key-vault?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Support&tabs=dotnet11#prerequisites

I am looking to do the same in Python
I tried to follow the code given in this page
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/samples/blob/encryption_usage.py
This page is not using the azure key

It is giving an error when I try to use azure key in that example

```
class KeyWrapper:
    def __init__(self, kid):
        self.kek = self.get_azure_vault_key()
        self.backend = default_backend()
        self.kid = 'local:' + kid

    def get_azure_vault_key(self):
        credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
        key_client = KeyClient(vault_url="https://xyz.vault.azure.net/", credential=credential)
        keyvaultObj = key_client.get_key("my-key")
        actualKey = keyvaultObj.key.n
        return actualKey

def saveEncryptedCSVtoAzureBlob(CSVData, accountName, accountKey):
    blobName = 'myBlob'
    blobService = BlockBlobService(account_name=accountName, account_key=accountKey)
    kek = KeyWrapper('local:key1') 
    blobService.key_encryption_key = kek
    blobService.create_blob_from_text(containerName, blobName, CSVData)
```

This example gives the following error
**ValueError: The wrapping key must be a valid AES key length**

Comment: It looks like the Python sample uses AES 256 (["A256KW"](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/samples/blob/encryption_usage.py#L30)) for key wrapping -- AES keys need to be 128, 192, or 256 bits in size. Do you know the size of your Key Vault key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Encrypting Azure blob storage with azure key vault" functionality is not available as of today

**The Storage Python library does not appear to support integration with Azure Key Vault yet. This support will be added in the future, and hence why there are no examples published for it at this time.**

This functionality is only available for C#/.NET

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-encrypt-decrypt-blobs-key-vault?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Support&tabs=dotnet11#use-key-vault-secrets

Answer (score 1):

•   In the ‘encryptionusage.py’ script that you have used for using the client-side encryption in azure blob storage in python, the ‘KEK’, i.e., the key encryption key or the wrapper key encryption algorithm is mentioned as ‘A256KW’ as in below snapshot which is a key wrapping encryption algorithm that uses a AES256 bit key.

[image: Encryption.py snapshot]

•   The output of A256KW algorithm is as follows from which the details of the ‘CEK, i.e., Content Encryption Key’ are extracted which was used to encrypt the contents of the azure blob storage and was stored in Azure Key vault.

‘eyJhbGciOiJBMjU2S1ciLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIn0.66xZoxFI18zfvLMO6WU1zzqqX1tT8xu_qZzMQyPcfVuajPNkOJUXQA.X5ZL8yaOektXmfny.brz-Lg.xG-EvM-9hrw0XRiuRW7HrA’ --> output of A256KW algorithm through which the CEK will be extracted.

```
  ‘JWE Header:  {"alg":"A256KW","enc":"A256GCM"}                         
    Encrypted key (CEK):  66xZoxFI18zfvLMO6WU1zzqqX1tT8xu_qZzMQyPcfVuajPNkOJUXQA   
    Initialization vector:  X5ZL8yaOektXmfny                                         
    Ciphertext:  brz-Lg                                                   
    Authentication Tag:  xG-EvM-9hrw0XRiuRW7HrA ‘   data extracted from the KEK A256KW algorithm.
```

•   Thus, the KEK or the wrapping key, i.e., ‘eyJhbGciOiJBMjU2S1ciLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIn0’ shown in the above output sample does not have a valid key length through which the CEK can be extracted. Also, in your case, the ‘get_key_wrap_algorithm’ command in the encryption script returns value of ‘A256KW’ from which a 256-bit CEK is extracted as above. So, please check the key length stored in the azure key vault according to the error received. It should match the above stated 256 bit specifications.

Please find the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-client-side-encryption-python?tabs=python2

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80966/what-is-the-point-of-aes-key-wrap-with-json-web-encryption